# Computer speed in flops

Tags: command, system-information

Nowdays, The speed of supercomputers are measured in Flops. Is there any linux command or tool that can calculate or gives the speed of a processor in Flops. If not, than how do we measure it.

Answer (score 4):

It may not even be needed to calculate theoretical value to have a tool.  Take a look at [this article that describes it](http://www.neomagick.net/zen/2010/01/28/calculating-flops-per-second-per-core-from-gigaflops/).

In actuality the measurement depends not only on hardware but also on the mathematical libraries you use for example in [this question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/88357/estimate-flops-in-linux) and an [article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) mentions [LINPACK](http://www.netlib.org/linpack/) as a benchmarking tool, however, it may perform slightly differently when used with or without [CPU optimized library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=CPC&utm_term=mkl%2Bintel&utm_campaign=DIV%2BUS%2BDPD)